# 'select * from [table_name]' is secretly a cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, cursor

A few days back I was asked during an interview if `select * from [table_name]` is a cursor since it fetches a number of records at a time?

If yes then of which type? **Explicit** or **Implicit** and why ?

Please, if anyone can elaborate on this it would be a great help.

Comment: Internally Oracle calls every statement a "cursor"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name elaborate please! plus, does it fall under the category of implicit or explicit cursor ?

Comment: @SabarishMahalingam Ok. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The terms ‘implicit cursor’ and ‘explicit cursor’ are from PL/SQL, where they refer to whether or not the code names a cursor using the `cursor` keyword. I’m not sure how meaningful they are when referring to cursors from other clients, but if you have to pick one or the other for a query you entered on the command line then ‘implicit cursor’ is closer. I didn’t understand the part about _“since it fetches a number of records at a time”_ at all though. A cursor can fetch no rows or a million rows.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The `select` statement in my question/title `fetches a number of records at a time.` Thanks though for the information you provided. Each piece makes the concept clearer.

Comment: I've summarised my comments as an answer.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes brother! Thanks for the answer. It clears our concepts even more to a deeper extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit cursors are those whcih explicitly are opened, fetched data, closed.

As stated, the usage of cursor have 2 parts:

1. definition of the cursor
2. usage of cursor

Definition of the cursor can be as

> CURSOR c IS SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_name

or

> FOR i IN (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_name)

The differences comes next:

1. The explicit cursor needs

> OPEN, FETCH, EXIT WHEN, CLOSE

1. The implicit cursor performs all above steps in the FOR LOOP statement.

Concluding, a SELECT statement is an implicit cursor.

Best,
Mikcutu.

Comment: The most exact answer answer among all. It clears so many others branching questions. No doubt @JSapkota made the point yet this answer is a bit more complete.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle internally creates a cursor to serve your select query hence we call it IMPLICIT cursor.

Whereas we call the following an explicit cursor which you create on your own to have more controls on it.

`CURSOR cur IS SELECT col FROM table WHERE condition;`

Comment: Seems every other cursor which is not `declared` and `defined` by the user would be called as an `Implicit Cursor`. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every query represents a cursor.

The Concepts Guide links from *cursor* to [*private SQL area*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/glossary.htm#GUID-4B296BAF-BAC8-4DE7-8128-464F4BA3C366), which it defines as

> An area in memory that holds a parsed statement and other information for processing. The private SQL area contains data such as bind variable values, query execution state information, and query execution work areas.

The [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm) says:

> An **implicit cursor** is a session cursor that is constructed and managed by PL/SQL. PL/SQL opens an implicit cursor every time you run a SELECT or DML statement.

and

> An **explicit cursor** is a session cursor that you construct and manage. You must declare and define an explicit cursor, giving it a name and associating it with a query (typically, the query returns multiple rows).

These are really concepts from PL/SQL, so I am not sure it is meaningful to use them for cursors from other clients such as a SQL*Plus or SQL Developer command line or a Java program. I'd say a cursor is only "explicit" if you name it in some PL/SQL code using the `cursor` keyword, and since you didn't (and can't) do that for a query from your command line, it's closer to the PL/SQL concept of an implicit cursor.

Comment: Well! This clears the air even more. Thank you for sharing the pieces and references. Really helpful.